# facebook like on UIButton ios

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-like

I have searched over the internet but didn't find a best solution. Some say use FacebookLikeControl and after learning it I find that it is in beta and may not be deployed. then i move to this [link](http://angelolloqui.com/blog/10-Facebook-Like-Button-on-iOS) there are multiple issues see at the end of webpage.  In **[another tutorial](http://nowbranded.com/adding-a-facebook-like-button-to-an-iphone-application/)** i which is implemented using FBSession which are deprecated.

I have got an idea but don't know how to implement it. On click of UIButton i open the url of the page which i want to like if user is already login otherwise open facebook sign in page and then move to desire page. When page is loaded in webview .

I want to simply check whether user like this page or not. There are a lot of button other than **Like** . when i implement method `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`  how could i distinguish between button. because in my app we give reward on basis of facebook like. User can click any other button rather than likeButton how I know that fb like is clicked. Is there a way or process to use javascript and get the id of button . and implement isClicked event to that buttton..

Because i have to save whether user like fb page or not.

**In Simple Words**

On click of a UIButton i want to like facebook page. and also save if user like the page.

Suggest me an other way round .

If this can be done by facebook sdk . please share a tutorial to like page. but my first priority is to do it without facebook sdk.

Comment: You can not check is someone liked a page. Like-gating is not allowed

Comment: @WizKid but i can count when user click the UIButton or shouldStartLoadWithRequest will call